# Is it possible to make a type an instance of a class if its type parameters are in the wrong order?

Tags: haskell

Consider the following type:

```
data SomeType m a = SomeType (m Integer) [a]
```

We can easily make that type an instance of Functor with the following code:

```
instance Functor (SomeType m) where
  fmap f (SomeType m lst) = SomeType m (map f lst)
```

However, if instead the params of the `SomeType` type were swapped:

```
data SomeType2 a m = SomeType2 (m Integer) [a]
```

Then the above instance definition doesn't work.

Is there some way of making `SomeType2` an instance of Functor? If not, are there any up and coming additions to haskell/ghc that would make it possible?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Biased am I, but I think this is a great opportunity to make use of [Control.Newtype](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/newtype/0.2/doc/html/Control-Newtype.html), a little piece of kit that's a mere "cabal install newtype" away.

Here's the deal. You want to flip around type constructors to get your hands on functoriality (for example) in a different parameter. Define a newtype

```
 newtype Flip f x y = Flip (f y x)
```

and add it to the `Newtype` class thus

```
 instance Newtype (Flip f x y) (f y x) where
   pack = Flip
   unpack (Flip z) = z
```

The `Newtype` class is just a directory mapping newtypes to their unvarnished equivalents, providing  handy kit, e.g. `op Flip` is the inverse of `Flip`: you don't need to remember what you called it.

For the problem in question, we can now do stuff like this:

```
 data Bif x y = BNil | BCons x y (Bif x y) deriving Show
```

That's a two parameter datatype which happens to be functorial in both parameters. (Probably, we should make it an instance of a Bifunctor class, but anyway...) We can make it a `Functor` twice over: once for the last parameter...

```
instance Functor (Bif x) where
  fmap f BNil = BNil
  fmap f (BCons x y b) = BCons x (f y) (fmap f b)
```

...and once for the first:

```
instance Functor (Flip Bif y) where
  fmap f (Flip BNil) = Flip BNil
  fmap f (Flip (BCons x y b)) = Flip (BCons (f x) y (under Flip (fmap f) b))
```

where `under p f` is a neat way to say `op p . f . p`.

I tell you no lies: let us try.

```
someBif :: Bif Int Char
someBif = BCons 1 'a' (BCons 2 'b' (BCons 3 'c' BNil))
```

and then we get

```
*Flip> fmap succ someBif
BCons 1 'b' (BCons 2 'c' (BCons 3 'd' BNil))
*Flip> under Flip (fmap succ) someBif
BCons 2 'a' (BCons 3 'b' (BCons 4 'c' BNil))
```

In these circumstances, there really are many ways the same thing can be seen as a `Functor`, so it's right that we have to make some noise to say which way we mean. But the noise isn't all that much if you're systematic about it.

Comment: newtype is very cool.  It's one of these packages where, when I first saw it, I wished I'd known to use it in all my previous work.

Comment: Whilst this is cool and works, it doesn't really answer the question as you still can't create an instance of Functor for SomeType2 directly (and just use fmap without the `under` wrapper function).

Comment: The answer to the original question is "no". Or at least, not in Haskell. To some extent, it would be peculiar to present a workaround had the answer been "yes".

Comment: Thanks, this appears to be the closest I can get to what I originally wanted. It is a nice library!

Answer (score 3):

This isn't possible, and I don't think it will be anytime soon.

Order of type parameters is thus important.  The last value is the one that you're going to "contain" for use with Functor, etc.

I tried to get this working by defining a type synonym that flipped the type parameters around and then used the `TypeSynonymInstances` extension, but it failed to work.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `newtype` wrapper which swaps the type parameters. But then you get a new type, and have to make a distinction of the original and the wrapped type in your code.

Answer (score 2):

The dumb answer you already knew is: flip your parameters!

For GHC to support this sort of thing without any extra wrapping, you would need something like Type-level lambdas, which are probably not going to be added anytime soon. (I'd love to be proven wrong about that)

```
instance Functor (\a -> SomeType2 a m) where
  -- fmap :: (a -> b) -> SomeType2 a m -> SomeType2 b m
  fmap f (SomeType2 lst m) = SomeType (map f lst) m
```

Since we already have TypeSynonymInstances, we might be able to hope for PartiallyAppliedTypeSynonymInstances sometime slightly sooner than never.

```
type SomeType3 m a = SomeType2 a m

instance Functor (SomeType m) where
  -- fmap :: (a -> b) -> SomeType3 m a -> SomeType3 m b
  -- or, synonymously:
  -- fmap :: (a -> b) -> SomeType2 a m -> SomeType2 a m
  fmap f (SomeType2 lst m) = SomeType (map f lst) m
```

Comment: Suppose you have PartiallyAppliedTypeSynonymInstances, and define `type T a = Integer`. Then we should be able to say `instance Functor T where fmap _ x = x`. So it's very much harder to say obviously wrong code like `fmap (+ 1) 7` shouldn't type check! (Even in the cases where you don't define stupid instances, you're making type inference all kinds of difficult)