# Haskell apply function arrow to only result type?

Tags: haskell, types, type-kinds

Is it possible in Haskell to apply the function arrow type constructor (->) to only its right-side type (for instance: (-> a)) to get a type constructor of kind * -> *?

Comment: Yes I'd rather avoid that as it would make things a bit more complicated. I'm almost certain I've seen it done.

Comment: Turns out that yes, I do need a newtype. If you post that as an answer I'll accept it so you can get credit for it.

Comment: `forall a. (->) a` or just `((->) a)` for some `a` has kind `* -> *`.

Comment: @htbta It has the right kind, but it doesn't satisfy the other constraint: he wants to apply `(->)` to its second argument, not its first.

Comment: @Daniel Wagner GHC has `(->) :: * -> * -> *` and `(,) :: * -> * -> *` with partial type-level applications `(->) a :: * -> *` and `(,) a :: * -> *`, but doesn't have type-level sections (like `(a ->)`, `(-> a)`, `(a,)` or `(,a)`) or type-level lambdas (e.g. `?b a -> (->) a b`). So using a `newtype` is the only option.

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069840/lambda-for-type-expressions-in-haskell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is currently impossible. There are certain limitations to Haskell's type system that allow it to be useful and convenient for most cases, and this is one of those limitations. Your best alternative is to use a newtype.

```
newtype FuncFlip r a = FuncFlip { unFuncFlip :: a -> r }
```

Newtypes are simply tags to help the compiler know how to typecheck and perform type-directed dispatch (typeclasses) properly. Presumably you wanted to flip the type arguments to provide some typeclass instance. That just means that whenever you want to make use of that typeclass's functions, you have to decorate any specific inputs with `FuncFlip`, and undecorate any specific outputs with `unFuncFlip`. This is slightly more verbose than desired, but it's not actually that bad, because it forces you to explicitly identify which instance of the typeclass you want to use.

You can create an instance of [Newtype](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/newtype/0.2/doc/html/Control-Newtype.html) for this, which may or may not turn out to be convenient for you.

```
instance Newtype (FuncFlip r a) (a -> r) where
  pack = FuncFlip
  unpack = unFuncFlip
```

Further reading: [Are there "type-level combinatos?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8248217/are-there-type-level-combinators-will-they-exist-in-some-future)